# Django: use my FORKED version of an app in some projects, not all of them

Tags: django

I am very lost on how to manage my django apps.  In most projects i use standerd versions of apps, but now i find myself forking projects and working on them simultaneously.  How can i use my forked version in some projects and the std version in others?  For example:

I have all my django projects in a directory calld `DJANGOPROJECTS` with a structure like this:

```
DJANGO PROJECTS
-PROJECT A
-PROJECT B
-APP A (forked version)
-APP B (forked version)

SITEPACKAGES (on default python path)
-APP A 
-APP B
```

I want to use FORKED APP A (forked version) in PROJECT A & APP A in PROJECT B.  PROJECT B takes care of it's self. Now how do i make PROJECT A use FORKED APP A?

If I put APP A (forked version) in a virualenv for each project i would have to update all of them each time there was a change.  If i keep it out of the virtualenv, when i make local changes to the forked app (without doing a git push) all the projects that use it will get the changes instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a much better way.  Setting up symbolic links is kind of a pain!  It turns virtualenv has a built in method to do this.

**Modify the path to the package you want to use for that environment in:**

```
yourEnv/Lib/site-packages/packagename.egg.link file.
```

**If you are using easy-install then modify the package path in:**

```
yourEnv/Lib/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

**For example:**

If you want PROJECT-A to use an app called APP-A located in your github directory.  Find the files noted above and modify the path from:

```
c:\users\someuser\documents\github\PROJECT-A\src\APP-A
```

to:

```
c:\users\someuser\documents\github\APP-A
```

Now PROJECT-A will use the version of APP-A in your working repository rather then the one in your virtualenv.  You can now work with the APP-A repository and the changes will automatically be integrated with PROJECT-A without having to push or pull changes.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by using symbolic links to apps in my virtual environments whenever I want them to use a shared version.

Comment: good idea.. I set up a project with virualenv and used mklink (windows) to symlink the local app in site-packages to the app in the loclal git repository.  Now when i update code in the app all the projects using it get the changes and i only have to manage the git repository.  Perfect.